# Wrong display of "à" symbol in HTML template

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

i have a strange problem with output of template of italian text into email. It forms as a html document, and this is how i define the troublesome part:

```
"...il documento che costituir&agrave; </span>"
```

when i open file with browser - it looks OK. 
*"...il documento che costituirà"*
But, in email - *" il documento che costituirà < "* - the question is where did it take "<" from???

Comment: Maybe if you add some more code for that part then someone might be able to help you. Without the code we can't. Also is this happening in which email client?

Comment: It's sent by SAP plugin. But i already solved it by just placing that string on other line, below existing and concatenate it with other string, so it won't end at this problematic symbol anymore. Somehow it solved the problem.

Comment: That's good to hear. Solve the question and/or paste it as an answer for others maybe ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just placing that string on other line, below existing and concatenate it with other string, so it won't end at this "à" problematic symbol anymore. Somehow it solved the problem